# Can I use temporary tables to improve query performance of mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to query data from UserMessage table, and need to get the message's user value from UserAccount table.
Under normal circumstances, we can use the following SQL to query.

```
select * from UserMessage m
left join UserAccount a on m.userId = a.userId
where m.type=1 and m.date between '2015-11-01' and '2015-11-05'
```

However, in reality, my UserMessage and UserAccount table the data are particularly large, however, the conditions of the above query expressions, do not need to participate UserAccount table, and particularly small amount UserMessage filtered data, only about 20. So, I use temporary tables to optimize the query.

```
select * from (select * from UserMessage where type=1 and date between '2015-11-01' and '2015-11-05') m
left join UserAccount a on m.userId = a.userId
```

So, I want to know, when the conditional expression in the case of table does not require the participation of associate judge, the database first to filter data and then relation with other table, or directly related and then filter data!

As we all know, the temporary table mysql will have a certain degree of performance loss.

Comment: You don't need to do that in this case. The database will only lookup rows in UserAccount if they match the criteria for UserMessage. You can see the table access order (and other useful things) with `EXPLAIN <query>`.